# Use another key for label in xng-breadcrumb

Tags: angular, xng-breadcrumb

I am using xng-breadcrumb for generating breadcrumb in my angular-11 app.

```
{
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: () => import('@abc/abc-helper-libs/home').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
    canActivate: [UserManagementGuardService],
    data: {
      breadcrumb: {
        label: 'HOME',
        info: 'home'
      },
      refactoring: true
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to use some other key than `label` key. Is there any way to customize xng-breadcrumb for this task?

Please help.

Comment: Did you check the documentation of the lib you're using?

Comment: ya, unable to find that option, i thought someone might encounter this.

Comment: Then it's not possible. Only thing to do is to request this as a new feature.